# Mongoose geolocation inaccurate response

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geolocation

this is my schema:

```
var onlineStatusSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    loc: {
        type: {},
        default:[]
    }
});
onlineStatusSchema.index({loc:'2d'});
```

and this is my query:

```
var query = onlineStatus.find({
     loc: {$nearSphere: [myLat,myLong], $maxDistance:10}});
query.exec(function (err,pros) {//response});
```

I am getting inaccurate data, i have tried changing 2d to 2dsphere also but it gives me all data which is within 10km or outside 10km

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to divide the $maxDisatnce value with earth's radius ie, `6371` approx for KM.

> $maxDistance:10/6371

This will help.